# Swift Tabbar Controller Bar button item

Tags: swift, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a 3 tab in my app.(First one is People, Second is Calls and Third is Chats)

When I add a left or right button item in chats tab, then I can see the buttons in other tabs. (I used show segue when creating tabs)

how can I solve my problem?

This is my code:

```
self.tabBarController!.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Compose, target: self, action: #selector(addNew))

self.tabBarController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `TabBarController`'s navigation items. You should set the view controller's.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Compose, target: self, action: #selector(addNew))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
```

Comment: In this way I can not see the buttons

Comment: in viewdidload also tried in viewwillapear and both of them did not work

Comment: It works fine for me... Is it in your viewController class?

Comment: Thanks for your help @penatheboss. I already fixed my problem.

Comment: Ok. I will leave my answer up for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. i did not use navigation controller in my tab's. Added navigation controller and it works.